# R Looping through columns of data frame, filtering by each column

Tags: r

I have a data frame looking at errors in data entry.
It has two sets of variables:

1. One set is error flags (their names will contain 'Error').
2. One set is information about the cases which were flagged (for this example, the column 'values').

I would like to loop through the error flag variables, filter the data frame by a value of 1 in each column, and then print.

My problem is that I can't get R to recognize the names of the columns as names to filter by.
I've looked for other examples, and I haven't hit what I need.

In this example, I have a data frame 'test_df', with four variables:  error_1-error_3, and values.
I'd like to loop through those three error variables, and filter test_df for rows having a value of 1.

```
# set up libraries:
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
```

```
# Create the data set 'test_df':
test_df <- structure(list(error_1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), error_2 = c(0, 0, 1, 
1), error_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), values = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

```
#  Pull the column names from test_df, retaining only those with 'error' in their name, and print:

names_test_df <- test_df %>%
  dplyr::select(.,contains("error")) %>%
  names()

test_df

names_test_df



> test_df
  error_1 error_2 error_3 values
1       0       0       0      1
2       0       0       0      2
3       1       1       1      3
4       1       1       1      4

> names_test_df
[1] "error_1" "error_2" "error_3"
```

Here is where the trouble starts - I can't figure out how to feed the elements of names_test_df into functions so that they are recognized as column names in test_df:

```
test_df %>% dplyr::filter(.,error_1==1)
test_df %>% dplyr::filter(.,as.character(names_test_df[1])==1)
test_df %>% dplyr::filter(.,noquote(names_test_df[1])==1)


> test_df %>% dplyr::filter(.,error_1==1)
  error_1 error_2 error_3 values
1       1       1       1      3
2       1       1       1      4
> test_df %>% dplyr::filter(.,as.character(names_test_df[1])==1)
[1] error_1 error_2 error_3 values 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> test_df %>% dplyr::filter(.,noquote(names_test_df[1])==1)
[1] error_1 error_2 error_3 values 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I've also played with looping through 'item' in colnames(test_df), and I get the same result.

Could anybody give some guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the string to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
test_df %>%
     dplyr::filter(., !! rlang::sym(names_test_df[1])==1)
#  error_1 error_2 error_3 values
#1       1       1       1      3
#2       1       1       1      4
```

---

Or another option with `across`

```
test_df %>%
     filter(across(all_of(names_test_df[1]), ~ . == 1))
#  error_1 error_2 error_3 values
#1       1       1       1      3
#2       1       1       1      4
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can subset the columns with `[`. For one column you can do :

```
test_df[test_df[names_test_df[1]] == 1, ]

#  error_1 error_2 error_3 values
#3       1       1       1      3
#4       1       1       1      4
```

For more than one column where we want to select rows where any of the column has 1 in it.

```
test_df[rowSums(test_df[names_test_df] == 1) > 0, ]
```